# 'await channel.send' return 'SyntaxError: 'wait' outside async function'

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, pip, discord.py

I'm trying to make a pretty basic Python bot for Discord.

This bot asks a riddle on a chat channel and the first person to answer it correctly earns three points. A wrong answer deducts one point (the points are stored in a .json file).

A command is used to check the participants' rankings and the riddles are randomly loaded every day at 6 p.m. from a .json file.

By documenting myself on the Internet, I wrote this script:

```
import discord
import json
import random
import schedule
import datetime

# Load riddle from the .json file
with open("devine.json", "r") as file:
    devine = json.load(file)

# Load user scores from the .json file
try:
    with open("scores.json", "r") as file:
        scores = json.load(file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    scores = {}

# Function for random riddle
def pose_devine():
    devine_a_poser = random.choice(devine)
    return devine_a_poser

# Asking to ask a riddle in a Discord channel every day at 6 p.m.
def poser_devine():
    devine_a_poser = pose_devine()
    channel = bot.get_channel(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
    await channel.send(devine_a_poser["devine"])
# Answer a riddle
@bot.command()
async def reponse(ctx, reponse):
    heure_actuelle = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if heure_actuelle < 24:
        utilisateur = str(ctx.author)
        devine_a_poser = pose_devine()
        bonne_reponse = devine_a_poser["reponse"]
        if reponse.lower() == bonne_reponse.lower():
            scores[utilisateur] = scores.get(utilisateur, 0) + 1
            await ctx.send("Bonne réponse!")
        else:
            scores[utilisateur] = scores.get(utilisateur, 0) - 1
            await ctx.send("Mauvaise réponse.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Response period is over.")

# Show the best users
@bot.command()
async def classement(ctx):
    classement = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    message = "Classement:\n"
    for i, utilisateur in enumerate(classement):
        message += f"{i + 1}. {utilisateur[0]}: {utilisateur[1]}\n"
    await ctx.send(message)

# Save scores in the .json file
def enregistrer_scores():
    with open("scores.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(scores, file)

# Add the riddle pose task at 6 p.m.
schedule.every().day.at("21:26").do(poser_devine)

# Loop to run scheduled tasks
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()

# Running token
bot.run("token")
```

Unfortunately, it returns the following error when executing:

```
python devine.py
  File "/home/devinette/devine.py", line 27
    await channel.send(devine_a_poser["devine"])
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

I'm using Python 3.10.5 and the imports seem to be fine,
what should I change to make the script work?

Comment: The immediate problem is exactly what is described by the error message: you can only use `await` inside a function that has been defined with `async def`. To call an asynchronous function from a regular (synchronous) function, you would need to use something like `asyncio.run`.

Comment: The [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)  documentation is probably a good place to start; there are also a variety of async python programming tutorials available (but no particular one that I'm familiar with and can recommend).

Comment: Thanks @larsks, I managed to modify the code and I no longer have this error. However, I now have the following error which seems to be related to the operation of the import schedule:

devine.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py:100: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'poser_devine' was never awaited
   self._run_job(job)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: That goes back to what I was saying about need to use `asyncio.run` or something similar to call async code from a synchronous routine. You can just put `async` in front of a function (like `poser_devine`) and call it normally; you need to either `await` on it or call it as I've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this error is pretty simple. All you need to change is to make your functions async. You can do that by just renaming `def` to `async def` in the function declarations.

This error occurs because you can't use `await` outside of `async` functions.